# Store custom class instance in IsolatedStorage in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

I need to store different objects in IsolatedStorage and i'm using IsolatedStorageSettings class to do that. Some of that objects are base types so stored and retrieved well. But some of them are custom classes instances and they stored well, but when i try to retrieve them i get instances with the initial values.
How can i store custom classes instances in IsolatedStorage and retrieve them?

Phil Sandler, i guess so. but i don't know what type of serialization use isolated storage, so i don't know how to make my class serializable. Private fields also must be stored.
Here is the code of custom class:

```
public class ExtentHistory : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int Capacity = 20;
    private List<Envelope> _extents;
    private int _currentPosition;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int ItemsCount
    {
        get { return _extents.Count; }
    }

    public bool CanStepBack 
    {
        get { return _currentPosition > 0; }
    }

    public bool CanStepForward 
    {
        get { return _currentPosition < _extents.Count - 1; }
    }

    public Envelope CurrentExtent 
    {
        get { return (_extents.Count > 0) ? _extents[_currentPosition] : null; }
    }

    public ExtentHistory()
    {
        _extents = new List<Envelope>();
        _currentPosition = -1;
    }

    public void Add(Envelope extent)
    {
        if (_extents.Count > Capacity)
        {
            _extents.RemoveAt(0);
            _currentPosition--;
        }

        _currentPosition++;
        while (_extents.Count > _currentPosition)
        {
            _extents.RemoveAt(_currentPosition);
        }
        _extents.Add(extent);
    }

    public void StepBack()
    {
        if (CanStepBack)
        {
            _currentPosition--;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentExtent");
        }
    }

    public void StepForward()
    {
        if (CanStepForward)
        {
            _currentPosition++;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentExtent");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the functions of storing and retrieving:

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings _storage;

public void Store(string key, object value)
{
    if (!_storage.Contains(key))
    {
        _storage.Add(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
        _storage[key] = value;
    }
}

public object Retrieve(string key)
{
    return _storage.Contains(key) ? _storage[key] : null;
}
```

I don't want to serialize manually every object to add, i want to make custom class serializable by default to store it in isolated storage (if it's possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My inital guess would be a serialization problem.  Do all your properties have public setters?  Post the classes you are storing and the code you are using to store them.

I believe IsolatedStorageSettings uses the DataContractSerializer by default.  If you want ExtentHistory to be serialized, you should read up on what you need to do to get it to work properly with this serializer:

[DataContractSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)

You might create a separate object strictly for the purpose of storing the data in Isolated storage (sort of like a DTO).  This will allow you to keep ExtentHistory as-is.